# How to tag previous months with sequence

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a datframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c':[0,1,1,2,2,2],'date':pd.to_datetime(['2016-01-01','2016-02-01','2016-03-01','2016-04-01','2016-05-01','2016-06-05'])})
```

How can I tag the latest month as M1, 2nd latest as M2 and then so on.

so for and example out looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c':[0,1,1,2,2,2],'date':pd.to_datetime(['2016-01-01','2016-02-01','2016-03-01','2016-04-01','2016-05-01','2016-06-05']), 
                   'tag':['M6', 'M5', 'M4', 'M3', 'M2', 'M1']})
```

```
+----+-------+-------------+----+
|    | c     | date        |tag     
+----+-------+-------------+----+
| 0  |    0  | 2016-01-01  | M6 |
| 1  |    1  | 2016-02-01  | M5 |
| 2  |    1  | 2016-03-01  | M4 |
| 3  |    2  | 2016-04-01  | M3 |
| 4  |    2  | 2016-05-01  | M2 |
| 5  |    2  | 2016-06-05  | M1 |
+----+-------+-------------+----+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a robust method, you can create a monthly period (with [`to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html)), then [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html) and convert to string:

```
month = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.to_period('M')
df['tag'] = 'M'+month.rank(method='dense', ascending=False).astype(int).astype(str)
```

Output:

```
   c       date tag
0  0 2016-01-01  M6
1  1 2016-02-01  M5
2  1 2016-03-01  M4
3  2 2016-04-01  M3
4  2 2016-05-01  M2
5  2 2016-06-05  M1
```